# Why translate cities and person names?

Tags: grammar, translation

I come from a language that preserves the original names of cities and especially personality names, so I was very surprised to find in Italian translation of this particular substantive types. I even once had an argument with one Italian friend about Bruto; he didn't understand that his original name was Brutus.

A few examples: cities - Munich (Monaco), Stuttgart (Stoccarda), Paris (Parigi), Frankfurt (Francoforte), historical figures - Louis XIV (Luigi XIV), Henry VIII (Enrico VIII) or other names - Michael (Maicol)  etc. In English there isn't any great figure called John Brown (Giordano Bruno), so why the Italian language creates such confusion by doing the reverse?

I'm not referring to the slight gender adaptations like Dublin (Dublino), but to the very brutal ones like Munich, which I actually confused with the french Monaco for very long time.

My question: is this a rule, it is done nowadays as well, or it refers just some old adaptations and why it is done? I think there is a loss of meaning in this adaptation and I had difficulties discussing with Italians about famous historical figures because of this.

Comment: It would be *Jordan Brown*, not *John*. Are you sure an English speaker will understand a Greek talking about *Efklidis*, or conversely if a Greek hears *Euclid*?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I have the impression that, at least about person names, Italian used to transpose more in the past than now, see Francis Bacon become Francesco Bacone. I don't think this tendency to transpose is so strong any more.

Comment: Did you discover what's *Benátky*? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg yes, very funny thing. I wouldn't have guessed it in 1 million years.

Comment: @martina yes Francesco Bacone was the initial example that really made laugh, but I forgot him when I wrote the post

Comment: @symbiotech what is your language? I was under the impression that in all languages, more or less, (some) foreign city names get adapted...

Comment: And then you realize that the guy who goes by "Pope Francis" in English-speaking countries is the same guy Italians call "Papa Francesco" - but in the official language of his minuscule country, he's just Franciscus.

Comment: Your argument doesn't hold for cities and peoples' names. It IS true that, under the fascist area, a lot of foreigner terms were forcibly translated to create a stronger nationalistic culture (Superman -> Nembo Kid), but it's completely unrelated to what you are describing.

Comment: John Brown was indeed a great figure; even though his body lies amolding in the grave, his troops keep marching on! But you are right that in English we don't translate the name of Giordano Bruno. We translate the name of Petrarch (Francesco Petrarca in Italian) and Desiderius Erasmus [into Latin!] (Erasmus Rutgers in Dutch), but not Bocaccio or Dante. We go a little mad with old names like Confucus (Kong-Fuzi), Tamberlane (Timur) or Jesus (Ieshua bin Iosef). There is no simple rule.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That *München* in Italian becomes *Monaco* is not really strange: looking in Wikipedia we discover that

> Its native name, *München*, is derived from the Old High German *Munichen*, meaning "by the monks' place". The city's name derives from the monks of the Benedictine order who founded the city; hence the monk depicted on the city's coat of arms.

I'm not sure you'll recognize the famous Italian city that Czechs call *Benátky*. I don't know what's your native language, but all languages I know of do such adaptations.

Every language has its own way to adapt foreign words; big towns (mostly capital cities, and there were *many* of them in Europe) and famous people are good candidates for such adaptations.

The results are quite strange. For instance, København becomes

- Copenaghen (Italian)
- Kopenhagen (German)
- Copenhagen (English)
- Kopenhaga (Albanian)
- Copenhague (Spanish)
- Copenhague (French)

For Italian one should remember that Latin used to be the European *lingua franca* and adapting words from Latin to Italian was too easy. So *Brutus* and *Caesar* become *Bruto* and *Cesare*. By the way, *Caesar* (as a title) became *Kaiser* in German and *Царь* in Russian.

There are stranger adaptations than *München* > *Monaco*. The Bavarian city of *Regensburg* is called in Italian *Ratisbona*. The Latin name of the town (which was founded by the Romans) was *Castra Regina*. Its modern name means “fortress by the Regen”, the river is named after the Roman town. Why *Ratisbona*? Because there was a Celtic village nearby called *Radasbona* or something like that and the town, for some time, was called with the Celtic name and so came to be known in Europe.

---

The tendency to adapt the phonetics of foreign names is weaker than it was, say, forty years ago, when still the “official” name of New York was *Nuova York*. Traditional names are retained, of course: it would sound strange hearing *Vado a Paris e poi a London*.

But nobody speaks about *il principe Guglielmo*, to mean the present Duke of Cambridge. However, it's always *il principe Carlo* for his father. Maybe it depends on the easiness of adapting the name: the former and the present Kings of Belgium are *Alberto* and *Filippo*, in Italy. I don't know how the present King of the Netherlands is referred to in newspapers, but he's probably *Willem-Alexander*. Apart from monarchs, the tendency is to retain the original name for contemporary famous people.

Comment: Speaking of Czech: Mnichov, Kodaň and Řezno :)

Comment: Aquisgrana - Aachen is another interesting example!

Comment: @writingthesis Which is Aix-la-Chapelle in French.

Comment: I can only hope the Italians do call the Dutch monarch “Guglielmo-Alessandro di Arancione” :)

Answer (score 18):

This is done in every language:

- **English** - Rome
- **Russian** - Рим, Людовик XIV
- **Finnish** - Rooma, Ludvig XIV
- **German** - Rom, Ludwig XIV

The reason for this is the same everywhere I suppose. Not everyone knows every language pronunciation, actually far from that, so nouns get adapted by the speakers to make them easier to say and refer to.

Comment: yes I understand the logic of pronunciation, but other languages have slight modifications, not Munich-Monaco, which could have been Munich-Munico, or Francoforte which could have been simple Francfurto

Comment: @symbiotech In the case of Monaco, I'm not sure how the process was, but "Francfurto" would not be acceptable according to Italian syllable construction and consonant clusters, it was adapted to have a proper italian spelling.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this, because it doesn't seem to be consistent rule. Ex "re Giorgio Guglielmo Federico di Hannover III" vs "George Bush", not Giorgio Bush and "per fortuna" not Giorgio Cespuglio

Comment: also there are lot of city names that don't respect italian spelling, that weren't adapted. Ex: Milwaukee, Johannesburg (which could have been easy called Giovanesburgo :) etc. So my guess it is an old rule, that doesn't apply for today's names. It would be impossible, so only the traditional ones remained.

Comment: @symbiotech There are manny types of loanwords, not all get adapted. Some are used in their original form (e.g. computer).

Comment: Actually, in German (at least in Switzerland) you say "Louis 14 (quatorze)", only schoolbooks would use Ludwig XIV. Which brings an interesting situtation: You write Ludwig XIV, but you read it (out) /speakIt  as Louis XIV.

Answer (score 12):

Every language adapts foreign names to its phonetic system and its morphology, both proper and common names (*Munich* > *Monaco* is not that different from *beefsteak* > *bistecca*) to be able to pronounce and use them.

Re “other languages have slight modifications”, would you consider Firenze > Florence, Napoli > Naples, Livorno > Leghorn, where at most 2 or 3 phonemes survive, slight modifications? Not to mention España > Spain and so on.

Finally, have you ever checked the German name of “Munich”...?

Answer (score 8):

for surnames of European people until XVII century, remember that the people themselves often "translated" their surname into Latin: for example, **Gerhard Kremer** is usually known as **Gerardus Mercator**. Italian people then used to think that Latin is just an old way to speak Italian, so they use the modern form and say "Mercatore".

For given names, during Fascism there was a strong force toward italianization of names (just to give an example, my father was born in 1934 and his name was Valter, not Walter, because W was not an Italian letter); the habit went until the late Sixties, with the anchorman Ruggero Orlando who talked of **Nuova** York instead of New York, but now the use is declining.

As for city names, the other commenters had shown that it is a common thing.

Comment: I always found *Valter* or *Valterio* very amusing given that the actual corresponding Italian name is *Gualtiero* (no disrespect intended, just a remark on how pointless italianizing names is)

Answer (score 5):

It happens in most of the languages. The native speakers adapt the pronunciation in accordance with their tongue. Let me give you two examples from a non European perspective

**Mangalore** is a coastal city in the Indian state of Karnataka. The name of this city is different in different languages

*Mangalore* in English/ Hindi 
*Mangaluru* in Kannada (Official language of Karnataka state) 
*Kodial* in Konkani (Regional Language) 
*Kudla* in Tulu (Regional Language) 
*Mangalapuram* in Malayalam (Official language of Kerala State) 
*Maikala* in Beary (Regional Language)

Indian state of Kerala has a lot of Catholics who follow the Syrian Rite. Some of their Christian names have evolved to suit the Malayalam (language) tongue.

Jacob -> Chacko 
Alexander -> Chandy, Idicula 
Job -> Iyob 
Anna -> Annamma 
Susan -> Shoshanna 
George -> Varghese, Geevarghese (St. George is called Geevarghese)

Comment: Interesting examples!

Answer (score 4):

Italians used to translate the names of the cities, with which they had had commercial relationship or something to do in common in XVI and XVII century.
That's why you find Anversa (and not Antwerp) or Lipsia (Leipzig) but Bruxelles or Liverpool remain the same.
It's in the history of those cities.

Answer (score 0):

The names of ruling monarchs, popes or the saints are still very often adapted in many languages. The reason is that these rulers or saints usually assume a Christian name which has a very long tradition of usage and a different, localized form in almost every European language.

The same is with many cities, this usage comes from a long tradition. I personally think it is a thing to cherish instead of taking over an original form.